# Is there a way that I can list channels in a discord server

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I use discord.js V12 and what I need is like;

> 1 = welcome_channel

> 2 = general-chat etc.

Also I am using this code below

```js
const listedChannels = []
    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
      listedChannels.push(channel.name)
    })
    const channelembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Channel list ")
    .setDescription(listedChannels)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setFooter("Write the number of the channel")
    message.channel.send(channelembed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by simply mapping the `channels.cache` Collection by name.

(The filter is because categories are counted as channels as well.)

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "text" || channel.type == "voice").map(channel => channel.name).join(", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
const channels = [] // create starting array

message.guild.channels.cache // get all channels
  .filter((channel) => channel.type !== "category") // filter out the categories (they are also counted as channels)
  .forEach((channel) => channels.push(channel.name)); // add each channel name to the array

const channelembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // make the embed
  .setTitle("Channel List")
  .setDescription(channels.map((channel, index) => `${index + 1} - ${channel}`).join('\n')) // map the channel names to preferred format
  .setTimestamp()
  .setColor("RANDOM")
  .setFooter("Write the number of the channel");
```

---

Example output of `channels`:

```js
1 - general
2 - media
3 - bot-spam
4 - announcements
```

---

I ran this in my server, this is what I got:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

@Sintuz & @Jakye i combined both of them and I changed some of the code and I made this:

```js
const description = []
let i = 1
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
  if (channel.type == "text") {
  description.push(i + "=" +channel.name + "\n")
    i++
  } else return;
})
const channelembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Write the number of the channel")
.setDescription(description)
.setTimestamp()
.setColor("RANDOM")
.setFooter("Write the number of the channel");
message.channel.send(channelembed)
```

And it works!